# Ruby 1.9 - Convert hash based off regex

Tags: ruby

> Need to convert {"P1" => "ABC", "R1" => "15", "P2" => "LOP", "R2" => "22"} 
>   
>   The hash keys could be in any order.
>   
>   
>   For instance they could also be {"P1" => "ABC", "R2" => "22", "R1" => "15", "P2" => "LOP"}
>    or {"R1" => "15", "R2" => "22", "P1" => "ABC", "P2" => "LOP"}
>   
>   
>   Into this {"ABC" => "15", "LOP" => "22"}
>   
>   
>   The matcher between keys is the digit.
>   
>   I'm looking for {P1.value => R1.value, P2.value => R2.value}
>   
> P indicating key and R indicating value

The way I'm currently doing it is looping over the initial hash and creating a hash like {1 =>  'ABC', 2 => 'LOP'} and also creating {1 => "15", 2 => "22"}.

I then loop over the first new hash and use the key to match the second hash and create the final hash.  {"ABC" => "15", "LOP" => "22"}


I'm sure there is a more elegant solution but I just can't think of it.

Comment: Wouldn't something along the lines of `H2[H1["P1"]]=H1["R1"]` be sufficient?

Comment: This would work if I knew every combination.  In my case the hash could change over time.

Comment: I guess you can have N pairs Pn/Rn, not always 2, right?

Comment: Correct, this is just an example hash.  The ordering could be any combination.  For every Pn you will have a Rn but not in any particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option:

```
Hash[h.keys.grep(/P\d+/).map {|k| [h[k], h[k.tr('P','R')]] }]
```

Comment: This works perfectly since it specifies which is the key and which is the value

Answer (score 3):

Check [Kernel#Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash). This works for any number of Pn/Rn:

```
h = {"P1" => "ABC", "R2" => "22", "R1" => "15", "P2" => "LOP"}
Hash[*h.sort_by { |k, v| [k[1..-1].to_i, k[0]] }.map { |k, v| v }]
#=> {"ABC"=>"15", "LOP"=>"22"}
```

A more orthodox approach without tricks on the order of the keys:

```
groups = h.group_by { |k, v| k[1..-1].to_i }
Hash[groups.map do |id, pairs|
  h2 = Hash[pairs]
  h2.values_at("P#{id}", "R#{id}")
end]
#=> {"ABC"=>"15", "LOP"=>"22"}
```

Comment: Wow, you just blew my mind.  I'm still trying to figure out how this works.

Comment: Check the docs of Enumerable, you have tons of useful abstractions there. At some point you should less write imperative and write more functional code (see https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming)

Comment: Only problem with this solution is what if they aren't in this exact order.  What if the hash was {"P1" => "ABC", "P2" => "LOP", "R1" => "15", "R2" => "22", "P3" => "PMB", "R3" => "34"}

I guess I should have been more specific.

Comment: I totally agree about being more functional.  I've been reading "Programming Clojure" which is a totally new way of thinking for me

Comment: Yeah, Clojure/Haskell/Scala/Erlang/Ocaml, those are languages you should have an eye on. About you other comment, update the question, but also state how we know which values are you interested in.

Comment: Hmmm, your new way doesn't seem to produce what I'm looking for.  Did you leave part of it off?

Comment: I pasted the answer in the console and it worked. Isn't `{"ABC"=>"15", "LOP"=>"22"} ` the output you want?

Comment: How does your answer make sure that P is the key and R the value?  It works as long as alphabetically P is before R.  If I change P to Z then it reverses the order.  The question specifically states that P is the key and R the value.

Comment: yes, for simplicity it assumed that you only have Pn and Rn, and P < R. I'll update it for a generic case.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"P1" => "ABC", "R2" => "22", "R1" => "15", "P2" => "LOP"}
Hash[*h.sort_by{|k, _| [k[/\d+/].to_i, k[/\D+/]]}.map(&:last)]
```